# IBM Watson Text To Speech Bower_Components

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson, amazon-polly

I'm pulling my hair out and would welcome some input/advice. I can't get any of the code examples for Watson's Text to Speech service to work. Or example codes for Amazon Polly or Read Speaker for that matter...

Every time I try to track down the problem it seems to boil down to something along the lines of "you need to install such and such (Composer, curl, Bowser, Drush, etc.) via the command line". That's all well and good, except for the fact that I'm new to web development and my company is currently using a shared hosting platform for which I do not have command line access.

Is there any way to get a decent text to speech engine installed on a shared hosting platform, or do I just need to bite the bullet and make the switch to a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your actually trying to do with any text to speech solution, you should at least be able to test from a command line locally and then deploy the solution in code to a shared environment.

Regarding [IBM Watson's Text to Speech](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech.html), there are no dependencies in and of itself. In the most basic form, you're just making a call to a REST API: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/#synthesize_audio

As an example, using curl from any command line, the following will return a wav file:

```
curl -X GET -u "{username}":"{password}"
--output hello_world.wav
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?
accept=audio/wav&text=Hello%20world&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"
```

How you handle that file will depend on the programming language you use, but it still doesn't have any dependencies to get started with the examples.